# Wrapping REST API with GraphQL / just using GraphQL

Tags: rest, api, express, graphql, backend

I am working a project where I will be integrating GraphQL to a backend Express server. Currently, the server's structure is much like a MVC pattern structure.

Controllers folder

- functions to query data from a MySQL database and return it.
- ex: file named `Car.js` and in there are functions such as `getAllCars()` and `getCar(id)`

Routers folder

- endpoints that call the functions in the controllers and returns it to caller
- ex: endpoint `GET /cars` that will call `getAllCars()` and return it

I want to wrap GraphQL on top of this and was wondering what if the best way to do this. As far as I know, each GraphQL type has fields and resolvers and the resolver is the one that will get the data (please correct me if I'm wrong).

So I guess my question is...

1. If I want to wrap GraphQL on this, in the resolver, do I call the endpoint that will fetch me the data?
2. If I have a controllers folder that is already handling the data access/modification in the db, can I simply just call the controller function in the resolver and don't necessarily 'need any endpoints'?

I hope this makes sense, I am still very new to GraphQL and am very excited to work with it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please find my answers below

*If I want to wrap GraphQL on this, in the resolver, do I call the endpoint that will fetch me the data?*

The GraphQL should always be served from a single end point. It is the query that changes but the end point will always be the same.

*If I have a controllers folder that is already handling the data access/modification in the db, can I simply just call the controller function in the resolver and don't necessarily 'need any endpoints'?*

This is debatable. It is a good practice to always separate out the handling the data access/ modification outside the controller like in a service layer.